# exporting to csv from db2 with no delimiter

Tags: db2, export-to-csv, db2-luw

I need to export content of a db2 table to CSV file.
I read that `nochardel` would prevent to have the separator between each data but that is not happening.

Suppose I have a table

```
  MY_TABLE
  -----------------------
  Field_A   varchar(10)
  Field_B   varchar(10)
  Field_A   varchar(10)
```

I am using this command

```
  export to myfile.csv of del modified by nochardel select * from MY_TABLE
```

I get this written into the myfile.csv

```
 data1    ,data2    ,data3
```

but I would like no ',' separator like below

```
 data1    data2    data3
```

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're asking how to eliminate the comma (`,`) in a *comma* separated values file? :-)

`NOCHARDEL` tells DB2 not to surround character-fields (`CHAR` and `VARCHAR` fields) with a character-field-delimiter (default is the double quote `"` character).

Anyway, when exporting from DB2 using the delimited format, you have to have some kind of column delimiter.  There isn't a `NOCOLDEL` option for delimited files.

The `EXPORT` utility can't write fixed-length (positional) records - you would have to do this by either:

- Writing a program yourself,
- Using a separate utility (IBM sells the High Performance Unload utility)
- Writing an SQL statement that concatenates the individual columns into a single string:

Here's an example for the last option:

```
export to file.del 
    of del
    modified by nochardel
    select 
       cast(col1 as char(20))   ||
       cast(intcol as char(10)) || 
       cast(deccol as char(30));
```

This last option can be a pain since DB2 doesn't have an `sprintf()` function to help format strings nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is another way of doing this. I always do this:

1. Put select statement into a file (input.sql):

   ```
   select 
       cast(col1 as char(20)),
       cast(col2 as char(10)), 
       cast(col3 as char(30));
   ```
2. Call db2 clp like this:

   ```
   db2 -x -tf input.sql -r result.txt
   ```

This will work for you, because you need to cast varchar to char. Like Ian said, casting numbers or other data types to char might bring unexpected results.

PS: I think Ian points right on the difference between CSV and fixed-length format ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use "of asc" instead of "of del". Then you can specify the fixed column locations instead of delimiting.